# Android - How to create this layout background (image inside)

Tags: android, layout

How can I create this kind of background on Android? I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

This is what I've tried

triangle.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-77"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="br.com.fornaro.armariovirtual.AccountCreatedActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/triangle"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/account_created"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/continue_label"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is:
[image]

How to fix this triangle? Or do this layout using a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Paint](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/instantanswers/8a779cf7-3362-4948-a65e-e3a78c86f9a8/download-paint) or [PhotoShop](http://www.adobe.com/tw/products/photoshop.html?sdid=MH16SLTF&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!87179436679!b!!g!!%2Bphotoshop&ef_id=WNxjGgAABR3IGUXu:20170330014458:s) to do is the easiest way.

Comment: Actually I need this via code because there's another screen using this kind of layout... :( Because of this I need to draw this triangle

Comment: Can't you make it a background image?

Comment: What you mean? a png image?

Comment: Means you can just use Photoshop to draw what you want that will be the image. 
You can make the image set in xml of background using whatever you want in layout.